# PayPal Guest checkout

Tags: paypal, checkout

I am trying to achieve guest checkout via PayPal on one site for my client.

Now it look like this:

[image: It force me to create a paypal with my purchase.]

But only thing what I want is just pay without creating an account (as a guest).

I want it like this:
[image: Guest checkout without creating an account.]

Do you know how to do this only as pay by card, not with creating a paypal account?

Answer (score 0):

To get that flow consistently you need to use the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/).  In your [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) request you'll include the following parameters.

- SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
- LANDINGPAGE=Billing
- USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

You also need to make sure that "PayPal Account Optional"  is enabled in your PayPal profile.  It's under Payment Receiving Preferences, or Website Payment Preferences, or something like that.

That will give you what you're after.

Comment: Still it is not always guaranteed :P

Comment: It is if you have everything configured correctly, and you have those parameters included in your request.  The only thing that may keep it from using Guest Checkout then is if the seller account is in a country that PayPal doesn't support it with, or if you're passing a LOCALECODE in your SEC request that doesn't support it.  Otherwise, it'll work.  At least that's been my experience.

Comment: That said, another thing to consider is that buyers can only pay through your site using Guest Checkout something like 5 or 6 times before it will start failing, so if the same person uses the same card multiple times on your site that will cause issues for them.

Comment: I have seen many merchants who has everything setup correclty, but still does not see the `Guest Checkout`, PayPal runs a security check on many factors. PayPal also has additional security setting which needs to be toggled(not offered to all merchants) so merchant gets guest checkout guaranteed.